# How to make vertically rotated links in HTML?

Tags: css, text-rotation

I'm trying to accomplish this:

[image]

with this code:

```
<div id='left_column_date_search'>
<a href='#' class='a1'><span>Dnes</span></a>
<a href='#' class='a2 selected'><span>Zítra</span></a>
<a href='#' class='a3'><span>Pátek</span></a>
<a href='# 'class='a4'><span>Sobota</span></a>              
</div> <!-- end: #left_column_date_search -->



#left_column_date_search { width: 36px; float: left; overflow: hidden;}
#left_column_date_search a { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#left_column_date_search a.selected {
/*  background: url(/images/structure/city-search-grad-selected.jpg); */
    color: #660000;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #9e4a4a;
}
#left_column_date_search a:hover {
    background: url(/images/structure/city-search-grad-hover.png);
}
#left_column_date_search a.a1{ height: 73px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a2 { height: 73px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a3 { height: 100px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a4 { height: 100px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a5 { height: 100px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a6 { height: 100px !important; }
#left_column_date_search a.a7 { height: 100px !important; }

#left_column_date_search a span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
}
```

But what I get is this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This would be easier to debug if you provided a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8RTaV/ , thanks for bringing the site to my attention ;-)

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get the menu bar as you want it and then rotate the whole thing instead of all individual links?

Comment: That't a great idea, gonna try it! :)

Comment: @thirtydot I'd like to cover all of them.

Comment: @Mike: Well, your current `transform` code does not cover IE8 and lower. Are you saying you want to support IE9 and all other modern browsers?

Comment: I found the code on http://bit.ly/2r4bqh and there it does support even IE6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution. I have updated your HTML and CSS to allow for this. Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8RTaV/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='left_column_date_search'>
    <a href='#' class='a1'>Dnes</a>
    <a href='#' class='a2 selected'>Zítra</a>
    <a href='#' class='a3'>Pátek</a>
    <a href='#' class='a4'>Sobota</a>  
</div> <!-- end: #left_column_date_search -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#left_column_date_search {
    background: #000;
    width: 36px;
    float: left;
}
#left_column_date_search a {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#left_column_date_search a.selected {
/*    background: url(/images/structure/city-search-grad-selected.jpg); */
    color: #660000;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #9e4a4a;
}
#left_column_date_search a:hover {
    background: url(/images/structure/city-search-grad-hover.png);
}
#left_column_date_search a{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg); 
}
```