# Vertical menu with rotated text at 100% height

Tags: html, css

I've followed this [How to make vertically rotated links in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713943/how-to-make-vertically-rotated-links-in-html) but I've to improve this solution.

I need to have a vertical menu that fits the entire height of the windows and divides it in three part (cause I've three menu links to show).

How can I update the code suggested in that solution?

Comment: How do you want the text? Centered, on the left of each section, on the right?

Comment: Centered will be fine, anyway it should be rotated like the linked solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    height: 33.33333%;
    display: table-row;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
.section .link {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    max-width:50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.section:hover { background: #ddd }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="section"><a href="#" class="link">aaa</a></div>
    <div class="section"><a href="#" class="link">bbb</a></div>
    <div class="section"><a href="#" class="link">ccc</a></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx3RA/5/)

Comment: if you in the future get more or less links, just change `height:33.33333%;` to `(100 / the new number of links) %`

Comment: This solution is working great. Just a question. I've link with text "Home Page" and even if it has a lot of space to write in a single line, it goes on a second line. What do you think it could be? Here's the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/kQmPYla.png

Comment: @s.milziadi I have updated the code to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `display: table` CSS property as follow:

**EDITED**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-child">row 1</div>
  <div class="container-child">row 2</div>
  <div class="container-child">row 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-child {
  display: table-row;
  -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
}
```

[CODE](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/Kdjkv)

the `transform: rotate()` allows you to rotate the orientation of the text.

Comment: if you'd like to rotate the text, use `-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */`. EDITED in the original answer.